# Stripey artifacts on mesh casting shadows on itself?

Tags: three.js

I am having some difficulties getting shadows both working on my meshes. I want the mesh to both receive and cast shadows, but when I turn receive on I get some strange shading issues as seen below;
[image]

The other side however is fine, looks like this;
[image]

Initially thought it was a normal issue but all the normals look fine and are as expected. I have recomputed and done a normalsNeedUpdate = true on the geometry just in case. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix, or even what the cause may be?

r71.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5554)

Comment: You can play with the `shadowBias` to diminish the effect.

Comment: @gaitat Hi - thanks so much, exactly I was looking for. If you want to throw it as an answer I'll happily accept!

Comment: Sorry- turns out that wasn't the case. I moved the bias too far so it shaded the entire scene so I thought it was fixed. Turns out my camera bounds were way too big. 10,000 wide by 3,000 high. Is there anyway to set a scale to the light/shadow engine or will I just need to scale everything in my scene down?

Comment: What is the value of your `far` parameter in the `camera` definition?

Comment: @tomatosource is it what you look for ? http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/SpotLight

Comment: I am talking about the fourth parameter of your perspective camera definition.

Comment: @gaitat its huge, 200k at the moment, but have just tried it way down and it doesn't seem to have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: @Atrahasis I've tuned those parameters down as far as I can and its a lot better, but still not great. Starting to think it may just be a limitation of 3js.

Comment: Try to bring it down to 1000-5000. Appropriate scale has to be applied to your scene.

Comment: some time ago i noticed that shadow artefacts were not the same depending on the number of faces of related surfaces. For example a plane with 4 vertices had more artefacts than with 100 vertices. Maybe it can help.